# Inequality with weird constraint.

Tags: inequality

$$3\geq ab+bc+ca\geq \dfrac{1}{3}$$

Find the range of values that can be taken by :

1)   $\color{white}{s} a+b+c$

2)  $\color{white}{s}abc$

For 1, I did:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab +bc+ca$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+ 2ab +2bc+2ca \geq 3ab +3bc+3ca $$
$$(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
Then I used the condition given to put the minimum value:$$(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(\dfrac{1}{3})$$
And I got $$(a+b+c) \geq(1)$$

Is this correct? 
And how do I get the maximum value?

Comment: From $(a+b+c)^2\geq1$ we get $a+b+c\geq1$ or $a+b+c\leq-1$. The maximum value of $a+b+c$ does not exist of course.